# Change delimiter for foreach in csh

Tags: scripting, csh

I have a string as follows :

```
set str = "HELLO SO COMMUNITY| CAN YOU HELP ME"
foreach word ($str)
    echo $word
end
```

Presently, this prints HELLO and then SO and then COMMUNITY and so on.
I want the delimeter for the printing to be | . SO the output should be HELLO SO COMMUNITY and then CAN YOU HELP ME. Does anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
set str = "HELLO SO COMMUNITY| CAN YOU HELP ME"

set delimiter = '|'
set special_char = '_' # A character you know doesn't appear in your strings

set words = `echo $str | sed "s/ /$special_char/g" | sed "s/$delimiter/ /g"`
# words now contains "HELLO_SO_COMMUNITY _CAN_YOU_HELP_ME"

foreach word ($words)
    echo $word | sed "s/$special_char/ /g"
end
```

Replace `special_char` with a character that you know does not appear in your strings. Just be careful with any special characters. I'd avoid `*`, `?`, `$`, `\`, and other tokens that might be interpreted by cshell. Rule #1 of cshell is that it **always** interprets them in the wrong way... :P